# Regex replace all newlines between ;" and ";

Tags: regex, notepad++

A csv like this:

```
A;B;C
1;"a";foo
2;"a
b";{456}
3;"c
d
e";{789}
4;"d

e
f

g";bar
```

I need to replace all newlines (CRLF) between ;"  and "; with some marker, say `<BR>`. The result should be:

```
A;B;C
1;"a";foo
2;"a<BR>b";{456}
3;"c<BR>d<BR>e";{789}
4;"d<BR><BR>e<BR>f<BR><BR>g";bar
```

All other newlines should be left untouched. I'm trying to do this with a Regex replace in Notepad++. So far, I've found I can replace

```
(;")(([^"])(\r\n)([^"])+)(";)
```

with

`\1\3<BR>\5\6`

This works OK in line #2, it deletes too much in lines #3 and #4. I could write a Python script for it if I have to, but I'm hoping it's faster in Notepad++. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the line break after `{789}` must be matched? Shouldn't `";` before it invalidate the match? Try `(?:\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))|;")(?:(?!;"|";).)*\K\R` and replace with `<BR>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! You're right about the line break after {789}, and your search seems to work as well. First time I see `\G` and `\K\R` in regex. Will look them up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `(?:\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))|;")(?:(?!;"|";).)*\K\R`
**Replace With**: `<BR>`

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))|;")` - a position after a successful match (`\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))`, here `\G` matches the start of string or end of the previous match, and `(?!^(?<![\s\S]))` is necessary to subtract the start of the document location match) or (`|`) a `;"` substring
- `(?:(?!;"|";).)*` - any char other than a line break char, 0+ occurrences, as many as possible, that does not start a `;"` or `";` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `\R` - a line break pattern.

[image]